# Complex trigonomteric functions

Tags: complex-analysis

If $z=x+iy$, I need to prove 
$$\sin z=\sin x\cosh y+i\cos x\sinh y$$
$$\cos z=\cos x\cosh y-i\sin x\sinh y$$
and from here I need to prove that these are unbounded functions.

How should I do that. Thank in advance!

Comment: do you know how $\cos{iy}=\cosh {y}$?

Comment: First you need a definition of $\sin z$ and $\cos z$.  Which one are you using?  There are many possibilities.  (Presumably those two formulas are not the definitions in your book...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you simply have $$\sin(x+iy)=\sin x\cos iy+\cos x\sin iy
\\=\sin x\cosh y+i\cos x\sinh y$$ and repeat it for $\cos z$